# Open Google Maps with labels

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I am trying to open google maps application from my application to show directions to users.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + sourceLatitude + "," + sourceLongitude 
+ "(" + "label1" + ")&daddr=" + destinationLatitude + "," + 
destinationLongitude + " (" + "label2" + ")";
```

But when GoogleMaps application open up it converts the above labels into addresses.
I want GoogleMaps to just show labels instead of addresses. How can I do that?
Example url

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=28.63382,77.220975&daddr=28.6328878,77.22014879999999(IcyCurls)&dirflg=w

I want icy Curls in the destination instead of its address

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the exact url with the values you get?

Comment: @ArthiRajgopal edited please check the sample url

Comment: Yes, It works for me http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=28.63382,77.220975&daddr=Icy+Curls&dirflg=w also check this doc for the parameters https://gearside.com/easily-link-to-locations-and-directions-using-the-new-google-maps/

Comment: @ArthiRajgopal u r just passing the name and if suppose there are 2 outlets of same name then how will we find the right one for that we need either lat long or full address

Answer (score 0):

Check this one which gets the exact route with the polyline drawn, We can do this only by passing the full address.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204&destination=314+Avery+Avenue+Syracuse+NY+13204
```